# iPhone, round rect button top half and bottom half?

Tags: iphone, xcode, button, user-interface

I'm placing a few round rect buttons next to each other, one on top of each other. I want the top to have the top rounded, the bottom to have the bottom rounded, and the ones in between to not be rounded.

This can be see in the Apple Contacts app when clicking on a contact that has multiple phone numbers, multiple email address, what have you.

How do you add these in xcode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those buttons you are talking about are not `UIButtons`, but `UITableView` with `UITableViewStyleGrouped` style set.

Answer (score 1):

Those are table cells, not buttons.

If you want something like that with buttons, you're probably going to have to draw your own and use UIButtonTypeCustom.